# Android get hardware Keys Programmatically

Tags: android, key

I have a Erisin pure android radio, and I would like to get the key information when the user press the hardware keys...

How can I get it from my app?

Thanks,

Comment: You are welcome to override `onKeyDown()` and/or `onKeyUp()` in your activity and see what you get. Whether you have access to all those hardware options is up to the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code of detecting harware volume up and down key

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {

        return true;

    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN){

        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```